# Python Macro to convert file names or read JPG and jpg as the same

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I am currently running machine learning through a kaggle database on google colab.

Everything looks perfect, expect for the face that images from one class are saved as JPG and not jpg.

Because of that:

```
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))
image_count#should be giving 2750
```

I have 10 classes with 275 images each(all training data, not testing or validation).

I get 2475, which is probably because of the JPG

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions, this one is probably simplest - check for both .jpg and .JPG:

```
image_count = len( list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')) + list(data_dir.glob('*/*.JPG')) )
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this I had tried ```image_count = len( list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')) or data_dir.glob('*/*.JPG'))))```

Comment: `or` is a logical operator, what you need here is to **concatenate** two lists, hence `+`